# Break lines in bash to HTML format

Tags: html, bash, loops

I'm having problems doing a break line between the IP addresses. They appear in 1 long horizontal line. I am able to do a break line on the first script, but it still appears in 1 line.

script #1 (showblock.sh)

```
command=$(pfctl -t bruteforce -T show)
my_array="${command[@]}"

for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
   : 
   # do whatever on $i
   printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
done
```

script # 2 (showBlockOutput.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
current_date=$(date)
output=$(showblock.sh)
OUT=oldBlocks/ipblock.html


cat << EOF > $OUT
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Blocked IPs</h1>
$current_date <br>
$output 
<br>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Comment: `$command` isn't an array, it's just a string.

Comment: And neither is `$my_array`. They're both strings.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `$command` or `$my_array` to arrays. You can wrap the variable in `()` to split it into an array.

```
my_array=(${command})
```

And if you want these to be separate lines when the HTML is rendered, you need to put `<br>` between the lines, not newline.

There's no need for the `for` loop, `printf` will automatically loop when given more inputs than format operators.

```
printf "%s<br>\n" "${my_array[@]}"
```

The entire `showblock.sh` script can just be a one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s<br>\n" $(pfctl -t bruteforce -T show)
```

Comment: Or insert a sanitized raw output into `<pre>$(sed 's/</\&#60;/g;s/>/\&#62;/g' <<<"$output")</pre>` tags. Because anyway, these characters has to be sanitized or it will mangle the html.